# I'm trying to use armtex in latin "mode", but macros do not work properly

Tags: macros, languages

I'm trying to name some variables in Armenian alphabet. For this purpose I tried using "\usepackage[latin]{armtex}". I use latin argument, since I don't want to have everything in Armenian. The problem is that i cannot use macros like "\armayb" or "\armgim" and so on. How do I fix this? I'd like to use "\armayb" just as I can use "\alpha".

I tried "\armfont{\armayb}", but that doesn't show any text when compiled either. The error code is: LaTeX Error: Command \armayb unavailable in encoding TU.

I'm using pdfLaTeX, but tried compiling it with XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and LaTeX.
Here is the document I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[latin]{armtex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\listfiles
\title{Test}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
$\armayb$
\armayb
\ArmTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Since most users are not familiar with `armtex` it would be very helpful to add a compilable document that shows what you're doing (even if it produces errors.) Additionally you need to explain what it means to say that something "doesn't work": does it produce an error, if so, show the error; if not, is it producing output you don't expect? It would also be helpful to say what engine you are using to compile with `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Armenian parts as argument to the font selection commands listed in section 4 of the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{armtex}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

$\mathartm{a}$
$\mathartmit{a}$
\armtm{\armayb}
\armtm{a}
\armtm{ա}
\armit{a}
\armit{ա}
\ArmTeX

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh... that was an easy fix. Thank you very much!! I didn't get it from the manual.